# Camera capture task - What to save to DB - Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, camera, isolatedstorage

My question is related to Windows Phone 7.1. After the camera capture task, I get the chosen picture which is saved in Camera Roll. How do get a reference to this so that I can save the same in my DB.

I mean, in web designing we save the url for an image for retrieving it in future. What do I save here?

**More Details - This is my requirement**

I have some items and each item has an image. The image is caputred using camera by the user. I want to save it so that, later when user views the item, the corresponding image should be shown.

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer after more research.

Got the idea from this [sample code](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Camera-Sample-52dae359) at Windows Phone Dev Center. Basic Camera Sample is the script.

**Summary:**

1. Capture the picture using the CameraTask from Microsoft.Phone.Tasks namespace
2. Save the Image in IsolatedStorage as a JPEG. Here we can give a filename
3. Retrieve the image from IsolatedStorage with the filename specified in step 2

Complete procedure is explained clearly in the same code [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/wpapps/Basic-Camera-Sample-52dae359).